# Best way to find if string contains any one element of a vector of string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, search

I have a target string and a vector of strings. I want to check if any of the string in the vector is contained in my target string and do something. Otherwise, do others.

What would be the best way of doing this. I know I can use for loop and string::find. But if there is any other function in stl can do this? Or using lambda function?

I tried for loop and it surely will work

```
std::string target = "United States"; 

std::vector<std::string> stringVec = {"United","America","Kindom"};

For (auto it = stringVec.cbegin(); it!=stringVec.cend(); ++it)
{

    if (target.find(*it)!=std::string::npos)
        cout << "Contains";
    else
        cout << "Not existed";
}
```

Comment: You could use `std::for_each` with a lambda but that will give you the same code.

Answer (score 5):

Abstracting away a bit from the specifics of C++ code, the problem you're describing is called the multi-string search problem. In that problem, you're given a list of pattern strings P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, ..., P<sub>k</sub> and a text string T, and the goal is to determine which substrings appear within the pattern string. This is a well-studied problem and there are some great algorithms for it.

If you have a fixed set of patterns and will be searching over lots of different strings to find those patterns, then the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) is a great solution. It does a small (linear) amount of preprocessing on the pattern strings to build a matcher that can then find all matches of those strings in variable texts quickly (in time linear in the length of the string to search plus the number of matches). There are a number of C++ implementations of this algorithm available; check Google for some examples.

On the other hand, if you have a fixed string and a variable set of patterns, you might want to look into [suffix arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) or [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), which, after linear preprocessing work on the string to search inside of, support efficient (linear, or close-to-linear) searches of that string for any pattern you'd like.

These algorithms have the downside that they're a bit complex not something you'd code up unless you really needed the efficiency. For example, if you're working on strings that are millions of characters long, then these approaches are probably what you're looking for. So in that sense, if you're searching short strings, you can probably get away with just using the code that you have, since it's unlikely to be a bottleneck and is fairly easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) will do the job.

```
std::string target = "United States"; 
std::vector<std::string> stringVec = {"United","America","Kindom"};
bool found = std::any_of(stringVec.begin(), stringVec.end(), 
                         [&target](const auto& s){ return target.find(s) != std::string::npos; });
if(found) 
    std::cout << "Contains";
else
    cout << "Not existed";
```

Your code will do something for *every* string if it meets the condition, not only once if the string is found (which is what you wanted I believe, judging by the description).